# jacocoTestReport always SKIPPED

Tags: gradle

**Expected Behavior**

jacocoTestReport work

**Current Behavior**

jacocoTestReport SKIPPED

**Context**

I created a task whose type is Test, and jacocoTestReport depends on the task. When I ran the task, jacocoTestReport did not work and I got the following information

```
jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
```

I find if I use the task `test` directly, jacocoTestReport worked fine. It makes me confused

the following code caused the above issue

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

}

task myTest(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()
    useJUnitPlatform()

    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    reports {
        junitXml.required = false
        html.required = true
    }
    jacoco {
        enabled = true
        destinationFile = layout.buildDirectory.file("jacoco/${name}.exec").get().asFile
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    // tests are required to run before generating the report
    dependsOn myTest
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        csv.required = false
        html.outputLocation = layout.buildDirectory.dir('jacocoHtml')
    }

}
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

[example project](https://github.com/scientificCommunity/blog-sample/blob/main/unit-test-sample/build.gradle)

**Your Environment**
`Gradle 7.1.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected, not an issue. just because I use the jacocoTestReport in a wrong way

see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18271

Comment: It's bad StackOverflow practice to have an answer which is just a link to somewhere else. The linked thread is pretty long, with a lot of confused users. Can you share *specifically* what you did to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue. I post what I found here and hope it will be helpful for somebody with the same issue.

- config: I am using groovy with gradle and spock testing.
- issue: When running test, I have only one jacoco empty folder generated and have no test reports.
- I run the following script to trace the information.

```js
 ./gradlew clean build jacocoTestReport  --i
```

- And I find that "jacocoTestReport SKIPPED". Why it's skipped?

```js
> Task :lib:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
Skipping task ':lib:jacocoTestReport' as task onlyIf is false.
:lib:jacocoTestReport (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:lib:check (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.
```

- root cause:

  - Jacoco uses the JUnit platform to generate code coverage reports, even when running Spock tests. If Jacoco didn't set the JunitPlatform and the test report cannot be generated.
- solution

  - add useJUnitPlatform() to test {}

```js
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}
```

- run test and generate test report after test

```js
 ./gradlew test
```

- screenshot for build.gradle and jacoco folders
  [image]
- references

  - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#ex-define-dependencies-between-code-coverage-reports-and-test-execution
  - https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/extensions.html#_integrating_with_the_junit_platform
  - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#using_junit5